# Error in publishing Artifact to maven central

Tags: java, maven, ssh

I have been trying to release an artifact to maven central repository. Had read so many threads online, that has to do with setting up a sona account and a couple of other things.

Anyway, my pom.xml currently looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.github.username</groupId>
  <artifactId>artifact_id_details</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>reponame</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
      <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
      <distribution>https://github.com/username/repo</distribution>
    </license>
  </licenses>

 <scm>
    <connection>scm:git:ssh://git@github.com/username/repo.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git@github.com/username/repo.git</developerConnection>
    <url>https://github.com/username/repo</url>
    <tag>currency</tag>
  </scm>


  <developers>
        <developer>
            <name>My Name</name>
            <email>myemail@gmail.com</email>
            <organization>My_ORganisation</organization>
            <organizationUrl>https://www.example.com</organizationUrl>
        </developer>
    </developers>

<distributionManagement>
  <snapshotRepository>
    <id>ossrh</id>
    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
  </snapshotRepository>
  <repository>
    <id>ossrh</id>
    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/</url>
  </repository>
</distributionManagement>


<build>
<pluginManagement>
          <plugins>

                <plugin>
  <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.3</version>
  <extensions>true</extensions>
  <configuration>
    <serverId>ossrh</serverId>
    <nexusUrl>https://oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
    <autoReleaseAfterClose>true</autoReleaseAfterClose>
  </configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
  <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.3</version>
  <extensions>true</extensions>
  <configuration>
    <serverId>ossrh</serverId>
    <nexusUrl>https://oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
    <autoReleaseAfterClose>true</autoReleaseAfterClose>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</pluginManagement>

</build>

<profiles>

<profile>
  <id>release</id>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>sign-artifacts</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>sign</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>

</profiles>


  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>


</project>
```

I run this command :

```
sudo mvn release:clean release:prepare
```

This failes with the error .

```
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 21.430 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-11-04T13:27:41+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/155M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2:prepare (default-cli) on project unicodenames-othersymbols-currency: Unable to tag SCM
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-push command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] Permission denied (publickey).
[ERROR] fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please make sure you have the correct access rights
[ERROR] and the repository exists.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.
```

I have added an ssh key as describe [here](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/) . Nothing yet. How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified the password in maven `settings.xml`?
Here is an example from one of my projects:

pom.xml:

```
<scm>
    <url>https://github.com/brutusin/wava</url>
    <connection>scm:git:https://github.com/brutusin/wava.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:https://github.com/brutusin/wava.git</developerConnection>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
</scm>
```

settings.xml:

```
<server>
  <id>github.com</id>
  <username>idelvall</username>
  <password>${github-token}</password>
</server>
```